# how to dump data into elastic search using BULKAPI

Tags: json, elasticsearch, nest

when i try  to dump more than 40,000 records (of size 100MB in JSON format) in to elastic search using NEST bulk API. 
Its throwing exceptions like the following:

Operation has been timed out / Underlying connection has been closed 
I have tried Set Timeout option on the index. 
I have made configuration changes in elastic search directory like ES_HEAP_SIZE= 2g, in

> elasticsearch.yml: 
>   bootstrap.mlockall:true

but still it is not supporting more than 40k records to dump into it.

Comment: You shouldn't push 40k records(100mb) at once into the elasticsearch https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/bulk.html#_how_big_is_too_big

Comment: Do it as batches of 500-1000 sized records. The appropriate size can only be determined by the hardware in use.